Need help for a manual calculation of MBR after /bin/dd of Virtualbox flat hard disk image to actual HDD on 32-bit P4 laptop (2003)
I have an old laptop which I am trying to install OpenStep 4.2 with Patch 3 pack (Which supports over 8GB and has a VESA driver) on to a 2003 laptop which is a 32-bit pentium 4 with 512MB RAM and a ICH4M IDE adapter hard drive controller which is backwards compatible with the PIIX4 controller driver (I've hex edited the PCI identifier strings for PIIX4 and changed them to my ICH4M which works).
I had to use Virtual Box to create a hard disk image as my laptop does not have floppy disks to read drivers before reading of the CD-ROM.
I managed to create 2.88MB bootable image on VirtualBox and then boot the floppy image of one of the GRUB frameworks that allows booting of disk images or .iso's (I forgot what one it was). This still could not detect the writeable DVD drive and boot the OpenStep CD-ROM.
The Open Step Virtual Box image is a 512MB flat image and I've managed to /bin/dd to my 40GB hard drive with C/H/S 16,383/16/63 which from research is LBA and the driver uses IDE command IDENTIFY to read the hard drive size.
The question is how do I manually edit the MBR so that it shows up as one 512MB partition on the HDD? Currently at the moment nothing is showing up. I have access to Lubuntu which when you use the Partition Manage it just shows a empty drive.
The Open Step image kind of works at the moment the IDE driver is having trouble as it does not detect my DVD-ROM drive (Which is ok for now). But I want to be able to create a DOS/FAT partition on the drive so I can transfer files between another OS that I want to install on the HDD.
No Nextstep, Openstep tags.
--- In Response to user Marcus Müller who posted comments.
I have used the page you mentioned to create a bootable CD which is how I managed to make a custom 2.88MB disk image that I can boot of USB using the GRUB floppy disk image booter.
The main problem seems to be the EIDE.config driver (V3.337 which supports PIIX IDE hardware, the ICH4M is backwards compatible with PIIX IDE hardware as per ICH4M IDE documentation manual) seems to keep showing a error.
PCI bus support enabled
PnP: Plug and Play support enabled
PnP: Plug and Play BIOS present
PnP: read port 0x0, max csn 0
ISA/EISA bus support enabled
ISA bus
DriverKit version 420
BusLogic Board not found at port 0x330
Registering: PS2Controller
Registering: PCKeyboard0
Registering: PCMCIA0
PCI bus support enabled
Registering: PCI0
Registering: EISA0
hc0: device detected at port 0x1f0 irq 14
hc0: drive 0, type 55, using geometry from INT table.
hc0: WARNING: using disk geomtry for drive 0.
hc0: Checking for ATA drive 0...
hc0: drive 0, type 55, using geometry from INT table.
hc0: WARNING: using BIOS geometry for drive 0.
hc0: Resetting drives..
Registering: hc0
hd0: 1024 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 spt
hd0: using single sector transfers.
Registering: hd0
hc0: ATA command 20 failed. Retrying... ; 0x20 READ_SECTORS
hc0: ATA Command: error=0x1 secCnt=0x1 secNum=0x1 cyl=0xeb14 drhd=0xe0 status=0x0
hc0: Resetting drives..
hc0: ATA command 20 failed. Retrying...
hc0: ATA Command: error=0x1 secCnt=0x1 secNum=0x1 cyl=0xeb14 drhd=0xe0 status=0x0
hc0: Resetting drives..
hc0: ATA command 20 failed. Retrying...
hc0: ATA Command: error=0x1 secCnt=0x1 secNum=0x1 cyl=0xeb14 drhd=0xe0 status=0x0
hc0: Resetting drives..

So I'm wondering if this conflicting error with HD image as the image I created on Virtual Box says the HD is only 512MB but the HD is saying to the controller it's 60GB. So I was wanting help with writing to the MBR that the first partition will only be the first 512MB of the HDD and that the rest is available.
The EIDE/ATAPI driver can not detect my DVD ROM so can't read the CD otherwise I would install of the CD-ROM.

feels like you should rather follow https://peterwong.net/blog/creating-an-openstep-boot-cd-2/ ("create a i386 bootable…" somewhere in the middle) and make a CDROM image that's bootable, containing the 2.88 MB floppy image you already have :)

The question is how do I manually edit the MBR so that it shows up as one 512MB partition on the HDD? I mean, assuming it can boot, it has a Master Boot Record (MBR), but there's no reason it should have an IBM PC/DOS partition table. Do you know whether that's the case? If not, the concept of "partition" in the DOS sense might simply not apply. ("MBR" and "Partition Table" are often used interchangeably, but the partition table is typically part of the MBR on, and only on, IBM PC-DOS compatible systems; and Mach/OpenStep have no reason to adhere to that, far as I can tell)
